# Can I use only one header for a bigger application?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, header-files

I am a newbie, and got access to a quite complex source code created by a team from the 90s who were all experienced and worked much together. The source code consists of about 60 different `.c` files which include even more header files, and most of these consist of only a few lines of code. One included file defines the `main` function in on of the header, while the others consist of directives like `#define`, `#include`, `#if` (`#endif`), `#else`, `#undef`, `#pragma` etc. At well as some structures (`struct`). Also you find an `enum` (which is more or less the same as a `#define`), `const` and some variables like `char`, `int`, `short`, `long`, `float`, `double` etc.

None of these will be used unless the `.c` files actually need them. As most of the `.c` files include many of these header files, it is hard to keep track of them. My idea is to put all the header files together into one single header file I will call `Unihead.h`. In case I want to do any changes I have to check up to 15 different header files in order to find the issue. I cannot see the benefit of that many header files. As I know it is normal to have a header to each source file (like `Soccer.c` would have a header called `Soccer.h`). If I got one header file I can a simple search and find what I look for more effectively, making the process much smoother in my opinion. Are there any down sides doing thing this way? (I will add comments to keep track anyway too)

Answer (score 1):

Don't think that this is good idea.

You also can combine all 60 `.c` files into one file. But, there are a lot of reasons of this source and header files structure. You should make try to understand the project structure.

Comment: Yes, you could add all c.-files into one, but these are more clearly why they are divided into parts. It makes it all more organised. Although the header files, are not in my opinion not a good organised system in the code. Generally the code itself is also quite messy. There are directives like #define inside the .c-file for example. As well as many variables...

Answer (score 1):

Well written c code, is arranged like a pyramid, with the main file in the top. Dependencies (function calls, enums, consts, etc.) will run downward in the pyramid. Never upward. This will help you maintain, extend and test your code in the future.

If you collapse all your header files, you'll also collapse the pyramid. You might as well, collapse the c-files as well then.

Header files are (generally) meant for the exposed parts of a given module. Eg. these will contain "public functions", "public consts" etc. Code like "private consts", "private macros" etc. are better kept in the c-file. This is why your c-files contains "#defines".

To me your code sounds like well written code. Eg. headers for each file (pyramid possible), small headers containing only exposed code.

Be careful that you don't destroy more than you add.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any down sides doing thing this way?

Compilation time may increase, especially if the resulting monolithic header file is large.

Also, there is a small risk of name collisions. A header might declare some function, and one of the source files (which doesn't currently include that header) might have a `static` function with the same name - this will cause a compilation problem. Similarly a source file might define a type for internal use, with a name of a type that is defined differently in a header file.